# Calculate progress of supportnumber in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Microsoft SQL Server 2016

I got the following table:

```
|------------------------|------------------|-------|
|      Supportnumber     |     Closed       |  Time |
|------------------------|------------------|-------|
|          1234          |         0        |   90  | 
|          1234          |         1        |   120 |
|          1234          |         1        |   30  |
|          1248          |         1        |   20  |
|          1248          |         0        |   100 | 
|          1256          |         1        |   10  |
|          1256          |         0        |   50  |
|------------------------|------------------|-------|
```

Each row can be seen as an activity. Such as "Install software". But for this example I did not include the summary of this activity.

Where Supportnumber is a unique number for each supportcall. Closed defines whether a activity within this supportnumber is finished or not. Closed=1 is finished. Closed=0 is not finished. Time is the duration of each activity.

Now, I would like to see the progress of this supportnumber.
So in example Supportnumber=1234

```
Total time = (90+120+30)=240
Finished time = (120+30)=150
Percentage finished = (150/240)*100=62.5%
```

So the requested result would be:

```
|------------------------|------------------|
|      Supportnumber     |     Percentage   |
|------------------------|------------------|
|          1234          |         62,5     | 
|          1248          |         16,7     |
|------------------------|------------------|
```

I'm by all means not experienced with SQL. But not a complete newbie aswell. I tried some statements with CASE but I still can't figure out how this works. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select supportnumber,
       sum(case when closed = 1 then time else 0.0 end) / sum(time) as finished_ratio
from t
group by supportnumber;
```

If you want this as a number between 0 and 100, then multiply by 100.

If you want to filter after the aggregation, then use a `having` clause:

```
having sum(closed) > 0
```

Comment: Cool, this is in the right direction. However. I do not want any supportnumbers in the result that are either finished_ratio=0 or 1.0

Comment: Neat, this excludes the supportnumbers where there is not any progress yet. (finish_ratio=0). But, I also would like to exclude the project I already finished (finish_ratio=1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Supportnumber, (SUM (Closed * Time * 1.0) / SUM (Time) ) * 100 Percentage
    FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY Supportnumber;
```

Comment: If `time` is an integer, this will return `0` for `percentage`; you could add `+.0` or `*1.0` to either side of the division to convert it to a `decimal` and avoid integer division.

Comment: @SqlZim : That's Strange. The same query gave correct results in other RDBMS. I have modified it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this query it may help you out .

```
select * into #status from (
select 1234 as Supportnumber ,0 closed ,90 time
union all
select  1234,1,120
union all
select 1234, 1,30
union all
select 1248 ,1,20
union all
select 1248,0,100
union all
select 1256, 1,10
union all
select 1256,0,50
)as a 

;with cte as (
select distinct Supportnumber,
cast(SUM(time) OVER (partition by Supportnumber ORDER BY Supportnumber range UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as float)Total_time,
cast(SUM(case when closed =1 then time else 0 end) OVER (partition by Supportnumber ORDER BY Supportnumber range UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)as float) Finished_time from #status
)
select Supportnumber,round((Finished_time/Total_time)*100,1) Percentage from cte
```